# Can't play sound on iOS

Tags: aframe

Cross-post from https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1684

**Description:**

I cannot get audio to play on iOS, both on Safari and Chrome.

What I tried:

- `autoplay` directly on the component. #1463 made me think right away that this wouldn't work. But #1463 description implies that it wouldn't work for Chrome for Android, but it **does** work for me.
- using `entity.components.sound.play()`, both with a setTimeout and with user events.

Both approaches worked properly in Chrome for Android and desktop browsers (Chrome, Safari and Firefox). In Firefox for Android, my app crashes even before I could try the audio, but that is just information, I'm not focusing on Firefox.

I inspected the iOS Safari console and network tabs with remote debug and there wasn't any error or something.

Also, as a side note, I tried the [a-wakens demo](http://ngokevin.github.io/a-wakens/), and it worked on:

- Chrome, Safari and Firefox (desktop), Firefox (Android)

but didn't work on:

- Chrome (Android), Safari and Chrome (iOS)

So, I'm pretty much clueless about how to get audio to play on iOS and would appreciate some tips.

- A-Frame Version: 0.2.0
- Platform/Device: iOS 9.3.2, iPhone 6, both Safari and Chrome 51

Comment: fyi, under v0.5.0 its `entity.components.sound.playSound()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Audio on iOS and probably other browsers require user interaction: https://paulbakaus.com/tutorials/html5/web-audio-on-ios/

Looks like you might have to dig around the sound component for the WebAudio source and call `noteOn`?

Also as a side-note, Web Audio AnalyserNode is still rolling out in mobile browsers. Chrome for Mobile should have it soon.